# Pack bool value into a char

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I need to pack a bool value into a byte. The byte can contain one of these characters.

(0 to 9 and A to F) i.e. hex characters.

I believe that these chars are essentially taking 7 bits so how can we utilize the 8th bit to store a bool value and retrieve both at a later stage?

Comment: 7-bits?  Looks like 4-bits to me.

Comment: Maybe you can use `uint8_t`.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? I ask because for a typical application it is very rarely necessary to be this efficient with storage (as opposed to say, `std::pair<bool, char>`), and doing so can make your code harder to read and in some cases slower to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
char pack(char c, bool b) {
  char res = c;
  if (b) {
    res |= 128;
  }
  return res;
}

void unpack(char packed, char &c, bool &b) {
  b = ((packed & 128) > 0);
  c = packed & 127;
}
```

To facilitate manipulating just one part of the packed value, you can also add functions like this:

```
char unpackChar(char packed) {
  return packed & 127;
}

bool unpackBool(char packed) {
  return ((packed & 128) > 0);
}
```

If you add them, redefine `unpack()` with them, not to duplicate information:

```
void unpack(char packed, char &c, bool &b) {
  c = unpackChar(packed);
  b = unpackBool(packed);
}
```

Example use:

```
char packed = pack('A', true);
std::cout << unpackChar(packed);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I have the resulting char within hex digits? For example, if char c = 'F' and bool = true, after packing I get res = '╞'(198). Is there some way if I can have res = (0 to 9 and A to F) ?

Comment: @PrinceSherdil Umm, what? The value of `res` is some packed combination of the original `c` and the `b`. Of course it's no longer equal to `c`. If you want to get the original `c` back, use `unpack()`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what I am saying is that, is there any method if we can further manipulate this byte such that the resulting char lies within 0 to 9 and A to F?

Comment: @PrinceSherdil I've expanded the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The number of bits that your `char` is utilizing entirely depends on how you're using it. If the execution character set of your compiler is ASCII compatible and you are storing characters within the ASCII range 0-127 in a `char` (perhaps by using character literals), then you have an extra bit to spare (if `CHAR_BIT == 8`).

If you're storing only the hexadecimal characters as ASCII characters, then you really you have an extra two bits, because you're using characters within the 0-63 range.

Nonetheless, if you want to store a boolean variable in the 8th bit of your `char`, you can simply bit shift a `bool` value and then bitwise OR it with your `char`:

```
char c = 'A';
bool b = true;
c |= (b << 7);
```

Note, however, that you cannot print out this `char` and expect to still see `A`. The `char` has a different value now.